# How to put textures on my tiledmap in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, textures, tiles, real-time-strategy

Im creating RTS in LibGDX and Im wondering how to put my buildings textures in proper way. 
Im using TiledMap to create my world, but I have to create some objects dynamicly.
I know how to do this by editing cells, but this solution seems to me a bit messy (my buildings are like 4x5 tiles large, so I would have to edit 20 cells).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you need to edit 20 tiles if you need to alter 20 tiles. Nothing messy about that. You can either cut up the building in 20 pieces (or more if it's height goes beyond the top tiles) or just plop it down on the bottom left tile and iterate through the others to mark that it has building X placed.

Comment: Thank you! I just needed to know that Im not missing anything obvious about that.